# Laravel component view cannot access its public variables

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, components

After one hour of trying to figure out the problem I decided to open up a new question. I am facing a issue that is pretty common, but no 101 fixes have worked for me.

My 'experiences' view component blade cannot access its 'Experiences' class public variables. It does not even call its __construct method.

**Experiences.php** *(app/View/Components/Owners/CardContents)*

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Owners\CardContents;

use App\Models\Owner;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Experiences extends Component
{
    public HasMany $ownerExperiences;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     * Get the 6 topmost experiences, with the highest preference number and then ordered by date.
     */
    public function __construct(Owner $owner)
    {
        $this->ownerExperiences =
            $owner->ownerExperiences()->orderByDesc('preferenceNumber')->orderByDesc('date')->limit(6)->orderBy('date');
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     */
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        return view('components.owners.card-contents.experiences');
    }
}
```

**experiences.blade.php** *(resources/views/components/owners/card-contents)*

```
<section class="timeline pb-3" id="timeline">
    <div class="timeline-body">

@foreach($ownerExperiences as $ownerExperience)
            
@endforeach
```

When trying to run the foreach, laravel says: **Undefined variable $ownerExperiences**

**What I want the component to do:**

Access the public *$ownerExperiences* variable (that is stored in the component class) inside the view

**What i tried and did not fix the issue:**

- Running '*composer dump*'
- Running '*php artisan view:clear*'
- Deleting the components and creating them again with the same content with '*php artisan make:component Owners/CardContents/Experiences*'
- Renaming the components, then renaming them back
- Putting *'dd()*' inside the class __construct method - still, the same error occured

**What I think the issue may be:**

Honestly the only thing I may have figured out is that I am using the @component directive rather than rendering the view with its <x-owners...> component syntax. Why is that? Well, I am dynamically rendering components, so I need to access the component name, which I can do only with the @component directive, like so:

```
@component("components.owners.card-contents.$key", ['owner' => $owner, 'index' => $index])
@endcomponent
```

Comment: `@component` will render the view directly and not go via the class. You might be able to use [dynamic components](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#dynamic-components) though